# Cordova Android Push plgin: on('registration') method not calling

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

hello guys i am using cordova, i have create one project. my problem is that 
 `push.on('registration', function(data) {});` this method is not calling.

**i am using cordova 5.4.1, and my phone is andriod 4.1.2.**

**i am running my app using phonegap desktop app in laptop with phonegap developer mobile app in my mobile.**

here is my project details.

```
cordova create pushProject

cd pushProject

cordova platform add android

cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

this works fine for me.

i am using following push plugin for phonegap app

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

and i have just copied it example project in my WWW directory, which is here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/master/example/www

also i have added cordova.js and corova_plugins.js file in WWW directory. and i have include cordova.js file in index.html file.

my index file is look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <!-- link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" / -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Push Demo</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card darken-1">
              <div class="card-content black-text">
                <span class="card-title black-text">Registration ID</span>
                <p id="regId">Requested</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="cards"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my index.js file look like this:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert('device rady');
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "<here is my google project id which ias enabled google could messaging api for android>"
            },
            "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
            "windows": {} 
        });

        push.on('registration', function(data) {
            alert("registration event");
            document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            console.log("notification event");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
            var card = '<div class="row">' +
                  '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
                  '  <div class="card darken-1">' +
                  '    <div class="card-content black-text">' +
                  '      <span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
                  '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
                  '    </div>' +
                  '  </div>' +
                  ' </div>' +
                  '</div>';
            cards.innerHTML += card;

            push.finish(function () {
                alert('finish successfully called');
            });
        });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
            alert("push error");
        });
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Comment: inti Method might expect a number to be used for senderID like in this [example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md) in order that this plugin can fully be registrated. All push notifications have to an unique ID in android at least so that a notifications does not intervene(overwrite) other notifications sent by other apps.

Comment: i have entered my senderId, i can share it in public that is why i have here mentioned like this.
var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "<here is my google project id which ias enabled google could messaging api for android>"
            },
            "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
            "windows": {} 
        });